# Angular universal : global typings error when using with an input decorator

Tags: angular, google-maps, express, typescript, angular-universal

I'm new with angular universal and used [this](https://github.com/evertonrobertoauler/cli-universal-demo) as a starter.

The problem is when I import a global typings like this: `npm install -S @types/google-maps` and use it as an input decorator:

```
@Input() f : google.maps.Map;
```

I get the error

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at Object.c (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:2601:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.c (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:3461:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.c (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:7441:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:3550:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:7566:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\tests\cli-universal-demo\dist\server.js:7589:30)
```

The transpiled code section of the server.js file looks like this

```
__decorate([
    core_1.Input(),
    __metadata("design:type", google.maps.Map) //this is the error line
], AppComponent.prototype, "f", void 0);
AppComponent = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
], AppComponent);
exports.AppComponent = AppComponent;
```

Note that only using as input decorator (for now at least) gives the error. Using as input to functions or inside functions doesn't give any errors.

Also note that google maps is included directly into the index.html as an external script rather than installed as a package which is likely the cause.

Comment: Did you install the [`google-maps` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps) as well or just the types?

Comment: @Saravana I'm using the raw google-maps library which needs to be included a script tag. This is a wrapper with basic async support but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Saravana no luck. That's just an async wrapper. Google maps isn't available as a package.

Comment: Did you try adding the script file directly in the `scripts` section of your `.angular-cli.json`?

Comment: Are you resolve it?

Comment: Still having the same issue. Could somebody solve this?